# why myeclipse's edit table function failed?

Tags: myeclipse

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p48hp.png)so,it's a very basic question

my myEclipse version is 2023.1.2;

my jre version is jdk vm 1.17;

i'am trying to use the edit table function,then encounter a problem:

Error: Cannot edit: superclass access check failed: class com.genuitec.eclipse.sqlexplorer.views.EditDataView$4 (in unnamed module @0x77c037db) cannot access class com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl (in module java.sql.rowset) because module java.sql.rowset does not export com.sun.rowset to unnamed module @0x77c037db

i use myeclipse derby database to test this function,and i try to change lower jdk version,and down to 1.8,but the problem still;

it is very weird,because all the other functions works,so do anyone know what the problem is?